# Javascript: connect multiple arrays containing paths and convert to object in a special way

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, concatenation

I tried a lot to get it work, but it only fails...
I have an array containing multiple other arrays:

```
let arr = [
    ["Users"],
    ["Users", "john"],
    ["Users", "john", "Desktop"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents", "Folder"]
];
```

and I need to convert this to an object:

```
let obj = {
    Users: {
        john: {
            Desktop: {},
            Documents: {
                Folder: {}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**But there are two more things**:

```
let arr = [
    ["Users"],

    ["Users", "john", "Desktop"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents", "Folder"]
];
```

should only return (because `["Users", "john"]` is missing)

```
let obj = {
    Users: {}
};
```

**and** it should also work, if the array is not ordered like that:

```
let arr = [
    ["Users", "john", "Documents"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents", "Folder"]
    ["Users", "john"],
    ["Users", "john", "Desktop"],
    ["Users"],
];
```

Can somebody help? :)

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Could you post your code or what you have tried?

Comment: To get the last thing done, just sort `arr` by length before using the naive algorithm to create the inner objects

Comment: @AanandKainth no it is no homework :)

Comment: @J.Maria I really had no idea how to realize that. I tried a lot with for-loops but I always got results that were not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this without modifying the input array:

```js
function dirToObj(array) {
  return array
    .slice() // prevent modification
    .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length) // sort by depth
    .reduce(function merge(acc, [prop, ...path]) {
      // recursively build object
      if (acc) {
        if (path.length > 0) {
          merge(acc[prop], path)
        } else {
          acc[prop] = {}
        }
      }

      return acc
    }, {})
}

let arr1 = [
    ["Users"],
    ["Users", "john", "Desktop"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents", "Folder"]
]

let arr2 = [
    ["Users", "john", "Documents"],
    ["Users", "john", "Documents", "Folder"],
    ["Users", "john"],
    ["Users", "john", "Desktop"],
    ["Users"]
]

console.log(dirToObj(arr1))
console.log(dirToObj(arr2))
```

#### References

- [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice): to make a shallow copy of the input array in order to avoid modifying the input
- [`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): to sort the paths by depth so that the object will be built properly regardless of the initial order of inner arrays.
- [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce): to iterate the array while passing and modifying a single accumulator, the output object.
- [Unpacking fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) and [Rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_the_rest_of_an_array_to_a_variable): to unpack each inner array and recurse into the accumulator object for each directory name.

Comment: Wow that is so perfect! Thank you :)